# How to delete the pickled object from a file?

Tags: python, file, serialization, pickle

I've got a problem while I was doing a program. My program is to create a class student and there are some variables under that and my task is to add the students in a serializable file and delete the students  whenever user wants to. I have written the code for adding the students but I am stuck while delete the object. I am very thankful if anyone could help me how to delete a pickled object from a file?

my code is:

```
import pickle
n = int(input("Enter number of students you want to enter:"))
for i in range(0,n):
  name = input("Enter student name: ")
  roll = input("Enter roll number: ")
  sex = input("Enter sex: ")
  sub = input("Enter subject: ")
  tot = input("Enter total: ")

  s = Student(name,roll,sex,sub,tot)

  infile = open("pb.txt","ab")
  pickle.dump(s,infile)
  infile.close()
```

and my student class is:

```
class Student:
     def __init__(self,name,roll,sex,sub,tot):
         self.name = name
         self.roll = roll
         self.sex = sex
         self.sub = sub
         self.tot = tot
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to pickle a list of students. Then when you want to delete, you can read from file, delete as normal e.g. `students.remove()`, and then pickle again.

Comment: Will it remove the required student or all the students sir? @Colin

Comment: You need to tell it which one to delete, e.g. `students.remove(studentTwo)` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle files aren't editable, and they were never meant to be. If you need to track individual pickled items, look at [the `shelve` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) - this lets you treat an external collection of (pickled) objects like a dictionary with string keys.